# Automatically selecting ipad @2x retina images for ipad3 from document folder

Tags: objective-c, ipad-3

I am developing an iPad3/iPad2 application. In my bundle I have both iPad2 and @2xiPad3 images.It is working fine when i use bundle. In iPad2 low resolution images are detected and in iPad 3 high resolution ones are detected. But my problem is when I access it from document folder. How can i do the same for document folder. When I use document folder instead of bundle only low resolution images are loaded. Here is my code.

```
NSString *docsDirectory =  [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fileName = @"image.png";
NSString *path = [docsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponentNSString stringWithFormat"/%@",fileName]];
```

I have placed `image@2x~ipad.png` also in the document directory. But it is not getting detected automatically in ipad3. I tried using image name without extension also. But the problem persist.

Answer (score 0):

in side your document folder no need to set  `image@2x~ipad.png`. just set `image@2x.png` is enough.

Comment: not like that. if you Used ~ipad in universal application for the purpose of knowing @2x image which is iphone and ipad.